# Remove-TcmQueueMessages -Queues PublishQueue removes the scheduled items from publishing queue

Tags: sites-9.5, powershell

We are seeing this issue after upgrading to 9.5 version. Running the below command removes scheduled items from publishing queue.

```
Remove-TcmQueueMessages -Queues PublishQueue
```

Has anyone faced the similar issue in 9.5 version and how it was fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To elaborate on Mark's (correct) answer:

- When you publish an item, two entities are created:

  - A Publish Transaction entity which represents the Publish action
  - A Publish Queue Message which (eventually) notifies the Publisher Service that there is work to do.
- When you do a scheduled publish of an item, the same two entities are created, but the Publish Queue Message will have a scheduled time on it (and it will only be provided to the Publisher Service after that time).

So, yes, if you remove all messages from the Publish Queue, the publisher will not know that there is work to do (including scheduled work). Note that the Publish Transactions will remain, so if you look at the "Publish Queue" in the UI, you will still see that there is work pending, but the Publisher Service will never pick those up anymore.

Ergo, removing messages from the Publish Queue (or any queue for that matter) should be done with care; it typically impacts the operation of the system.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information Rick - hadn't considered the implications (from an editor/publisher perspective on the UX)!

Answer (score 3):

You're specifically referring to `Remove-TcmQueueMessages -Queues PublishQueue` When you say that you're seeing the issue *after upgrading to 9.5* are you stating that the deletion of items in a scheduled state were not deleted in the previous version(s) of Tridion Sites?

Here, you are purging the Queue. **Not** specifying the items within a queue you wish to remove.

- https://docs.rws.com/783502/105947/sdl-tridion-sites-9-1/purging-queues
- https://gateway.sdl.com/apex/communityknowledge?articleName=000012837

Are you meaning to use `Remove-TcmPublishTransactions`
Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.rws.com/816112/104162/sdl-tridion-sites-9-5-main-documentation/purging-finished-publish-transactions), I see that this will

> {purge} the publish transactions that meet the criteria you specified and to which you have access

Comment: So deletion of items(scheduled items) from publishing queue if we run the command "Remove-TcmQueueMessages" is expected behavior?

Comment: Well - the command is to remove *queue* messages... so it's removing all messages from the queue; so I'd expect it is expected behaviour. Your question inferred that it didn't do this previously but I suspect that's just the wording? It would seem to me that *your* requirement is to remove publish transactions of a particular sort (e.g. successful, failed) and the script I've linked to will do that.